# how to select a specific sub ou from multiple ous in AD using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to pull a list of all users within a specific sub folder that is Common from many other Ou's. For example.

```
     Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Platform,OU=DeltaV,DC=RootDomain,DC=com" -Filter *
```

And :

```
    "OU=Platform,OU=RootV,DC=ChildDomain,DC=RootDomain,DC=com"
```

Something along the line of :

```
     Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Platform,OU=*,DC=ROotDomain,DC=com" -Filter *
```

I'm not sure if this is possible with PowerShell without writing a large script designated each location.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Even your example would not produce the results that you want. It would not match DC=winmain and DC=RootDomain both.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking too carefully. I will edit to fix that.

Comment: Your example still doesn't make a lot of sense. You say that you want to be able to put a wildcard on the OU but have it know that it still needs to check other cild DCs? In that case just set the search root to the top level domain that you want to look at then use a Where-Object filter on the output to look for OU=Platform.

Comment: Thank you for the tip,  That put me on the right track. I appreciate your help .

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You should either post the answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

WOrking with EBGreen, I found the answer:

A simple query:

```
   Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties *  | where-object {$_ -like  "*OU=Platform*" } | select mailNickname, l, DistinguishedName | export-CSV -path "c:\workspace\Pull.csv"
```

This enabled me to pull all AD, used a where object to narrow down the OU to Platform, then select the relevant data.

Comment: I hope you realize, this is only pulling user accounts.  Otherwise, I might also suggest you search for " *OU=Platform,OU= *" so that if you have an OU like "Platforms Decomissioned" it's not going to match erroneously.